# How I can make a webservice to be published in multiple addresses (endpoints) using CXF with Grails?

Tags: grails, cxf

I am implementing a web Service in grails using CXF. I want to publish my endpoint in several addresses for a single Service. Like as:

localhost:8080/myapplication/Services/myservice1
localhost:8080/myapplication/Services/myservice2

And how can acheive that endpoint addresses dynamically?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [CXF plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/cxf) for grails. At the end of [readme](https://github.com/Grails-Plugin-Consortium/grails-cxf) there is even a demo project.